# jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 11660

Tags: swift, alamofire

im getting response and data in postman but not getting data in swift using Alamofire

```
    let params:[String:Any] = ["company_id" : company_id!,"username" : username!, "password" : password!] as [String : Any]
    let header : [String:String] = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
    Alamofire.request("url",method: .post, parameters: params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)
            print("string:\(String(describing: response.result.value))")

            print(data)
            print(response.result.value)
        case .failure(let error)
            print("Error Messsage: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            if let data = response.data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8){
                print("Server Error: " + str)
            }
            debugPrint(error as Any)
            print("===========================\n\n")


        }

    }
```

I'm getting data in postman as follows

```
"productandservices": {
    "1": "BARCODE PRINTER",
    "2": "ID CARD PRINTER",
    "3": "B-FV4T GS",
    "4": "B-SX Platen Roll",
    "5": "45700 - FARGO - DTC 4500 Upgrade- dtc printer head",
    "6": "07FM0016300F- B-SX Platen Roll -ASYB PlattenRoller",
    "8": "productandservice_name",
    "9": "07FM0016300F - B-SX Platen Roll (ASYB PlattenRoller)",
    "10": "07FM00973100 - Printer Head (ASYB-HEAD-SA4T FRU (ROHS))",
    "11": "51416 - DTC 1500 PRINTER (DTC 1500E)",
    "12": "51976 - Fargo Card Printer (C50 card printer)",
    "13": "7FM07358000 - BLACK MARK SENSOR (B-852-TS22-QP-R)",
    "14": "81754 - FARGO (PVC ultra card)",
    "15": "CO-11118000 - SLIT SENSOR TLP1242(C6 F) (B-852-TS22-QP-R)",
    "16": "FMHEOO10802 - SUPPLY HOLDER (B-852-TS22-QP-R)",
    "17": "MHT00022 - Scanner ()",
    "18": "MHT00054 - Scanner ()",
    "19": "MHT00337 - BARCODE RIBBON (110*270)",
    "20": "MHTS0001 - ID Soft-Card Printing Database interfacing (SINGLE USER)",
    "21": "MTH00224 -  Pre printed Cards (HMP Dual side PP card)",
    "22": "OFMCC0054701F - Toshiba Spares (B-852)",
    "23": "OTSBC0113901F - POWER SUPPLY UNIT (EX4)",
    "24": "MHT00340 - BARCODE RIBBON (110*270)",
    "25": "MHT00324 - BARCODE RIBBON (WAXD RIBBON)",
    "26": "MHT00325 - BARCOSE RIBBON (110*100)",
    "27": "MHT00326 - BARCOSE RIBBON (MAGIC ID CARD RIBBON)",
    "28": "4 - BARCOSE RIBBON (110*100)",
    "29": "TH-1000-RII - Cleaner (Thermal Head cleaner)",
    "30": "MHT00353 - Datacard color Ribbon (535000-003)",
    "31": "45616 - DTC 1500 RESIN BLACK (RESIN BLACK)",
    "32": "51416 - FARGO (DTC 1500E)",
    "33": "86177 - FARGO (Cleaning KIT for DTC Printer)",
    "34": "89200 - FARGO (Cleaning KIT for HDP 5000)",
    "35": "86091 - FARGO HDP 5000 (HDP 5000)",
    "36": "MHT00368 - HONEY WELL SCANNER (YJ5900- 1- USB)",
    "37": "MHT00291 - Motorolla (DS6707 - SRBU0100ZY)",
    "38": "7FM07076000 - PRINT HEAD  (B-EX6T3 200 DPI)",
    "39": "FMBC0089706 - Printer Head ()",
    "40": "7FMBC0073203FF - Printer Head (B452 Head)",
    "41": "7FM07075000 - PRINTER HEAD  (B-EX6T3 300 DPI)",
    "42": "7FM06977000 - PRINTER HEAD (B-EX6T1 300 DPI)",
    "43": "7FM01584000 - Printer Head (B SX8)",
    "44": "7FM03784000 - Printer Head (B EV4T 203)",
    "45": "7FM03785000 - Printer Head (EV4T 300)",
    "46": "7FM06507000 - Printer Head (B FV4T203)",
    "47": "07FM00973100F - Printer Head (ASYB-HEAD-SA4T FRU (ROHS))",
    "48": "07FM00973000F - Printer Head (B-SA4T Print Head (203 dpi))",
    "49": "07FM01641000F - Printer Head (B SX4)",
    "50": "07FM01641100 - Printer Head (B SX5T)",
    "51": "07FM01641100F - Printer Head (B SX5T)",
    "52": "07FM06508000 - PRINTER HEAD (FV4T-300DPI)",
    "53": "OTSBC0117001F - Printer Head (B EX4 T1 203)",
    "54": "OTSBC0117201F - Printer Head (B EX4 T1 300)",
    "55": "OTSBC0145001F - Printer Head (B EX4 T2 GS)",
    "56": "OTSBC0145101F - Printer Head ()",
    "57": "MHT00354 - Printer Head CD 800 (CD800)",
    "58": "45614 -  RIBBON (45614 1/2 PANEL)",
    "59": "45610 -  RIBBON (YMCKO 500)",
    "60": "7FM00531300 - RIBBON SHAFT ASS\"Y (FEED) ()",
    "61": "FMBC0034005 - RIBBON SHAFT ASS\"Y(TAKE-UP) ()",
    "62": "MHT00300 - ROPE (TUBE ROPE (Flat))",
    "63": "MHT00301 - ROPE (TUBE ROPE-HOLDER(Flat))",
    "64": "MHT00302 - ROPE (TUBE ROPE (Multi color))",
    "65": "MHT00228 - ROPE (TUBE ROPE-HOLDER)",
    "66": "MHT00289 - Scanner (New)",
    "67": "MHT00303 - Tag (Jewellery Tag with Left side Bat)",
    "68": "MHT00299 - Tag (EasyBand Wrist Band)",
    "69": "MHT00338 - Tag (Yellow-EasyBand Wrist Band)",
    "70": "MHT00339 - Tag (Neon Orange-EasyBand Wrist Band)",
    "71": "MHT00329 - THERMAL ROLL (79*50M)",
    "72": "7fm07063000 - TOSHIBA ACCESSORIES (B-EX6T(200 DPI))",
    "73": "18221165221 - TOSHIBA ACCESSORIES (B SA904 H QM R PEEL OFF MODULE )",
    "74": "MHT00223 - Toshiba Spares (B-4205-QM-R)",
    "75": "MHT00352 - transer heat assemply ()",
    "76": "D910704 -    TRANSFER ASSEMPLY (HDP 5000)",
    "77": "MHT00377 - TSC TTP 244 PRO PRINTER (TTP 244 PRO PRINTER )",
    "78": "45613 - YMCKO  HALF-PANEL RIBBON (YMCKO 850 IMAGES)",
    "79": "00.8082.002 - Barcode Printer (C168/200S)",
    "80": "18221165222 - Barcode Printer (B-SA704-RS-QM-R)",
    "81": "18221165228 - Barcode Printer (B-SA704-RTC-QM-R)",
    "82": "18221165233 - Barcode Printer (B-SA704-IO-QM-R)",
    "83": "18221165237 - Barcode Printer (B-9904-R2-QM-R)",
    "84": "18221165238 - Barcode Printer (B-9904-H-QM-R)",
    "85": "18221165244 - Barcode Printer (B-7208-QM-R)",
    "86": "18221165247 - Barcode Printer (B-SX208-QM-R)",
    "87": "18221165248 - Barcode Printer (B-SX908-H-QM-R)",
    "88": "18221165252 - Barcode Printer (B-SX908-R-QM-R)",
    "89": "18221165272 - Barcode Printer (B-EP804-BT-QM-R)",
    "90": "18221165273 - Barcode Printer (B-EP800-CHG-QM-R)",
    "91": "18221165274 - Barcode Printer (B-EP800-CHG6-QM-R)",
    "92": "18221165275 - Barcode Printer (B-EP800-AC-QM-R)",
    "93": "18221165276 - Barcode Printer (B-EP802-DC12-QM-R)",
    "94": "18221165277 - Barcode Printer (B-EP800-DC48-QM-R)",
    "95": "18221165284 - Barcode Printer (B-EP700-BLTH-QM-R)",
    "96": "18221165285 - Barcode Printer (B-EP700-WLAN-QM-R)",
    "97": "18221165287 - Barcode Printer (B-7704-RS-QM-R)",
    "98": "18221165290 - Barcode Printer (B-EV204-F-QM-R)",
    "99": "18221165291 - Barcode Printer (B-EV204-P-QM-R)",
    "100": "18221165293 - Barcode Printer (B-EV904-H-QM-R)",
    "101": "18221165294 - Barcode Printer (B-EV904-PH-QM-R)",
    "102": "18221165296 - Barcode Printer (B-EV904-AC-QM-R)",
    "103": "18221165317 - Barcode Printer (B-EX204-QM-R)",
    "104": "18221165318 - Barcode Printer (B-EX204-R-QM-R)",
    "105": "18221165319 - Barcode Printer (B-EX904-H-QM-R)",
    "106": "18221165327 - Barcode Printer (B-EX700-RTC-QM-R)",
    "107": "10021165221 - Barcode Printer (B-SA904-H-QM-R)",
    "108": "10021165222 - Barcode Printer (B-SA704-RS-QM-R)",
    "109": "10021165228 - Barcode Printer (B-SA704-RTC-QM-R)",
    "110": "10021165229 - Barcode Printer (B-SA204P-QM-R)",
    "111": "10021165230 - Barcode Printer (B-SA904P-H-QM-R)",
    "112": "10021165241 - Barcode Printer (B-9700-USB-QM-R)",
    "113": "10021165242 - Barcode Printer (B-7704-IO-QM-R)",
    "114": "10021165257 - Barcode Printer (B-SA704-WLAN-QM-R)",
    "115": "10021165269 - Barcode Printer (B-7904-H-QM-R)",
    "116": "10021165270 - Barcode Printer (B-7204-QM-R)",
    "117": "10021165271 - Barcode Printer (B-EP802-BT-QM-R)",
    "118": "10021165278 - Barcode Printer (B-EP900-SS-QM-R)",
    "119": "10021165279 - Barcode Printer (B-EP902-CC-QM-R)",
    "120": "10021165280 - Barcode Printer (B-EP904-CC-QM-R)",
    "121": "10021165281 - Barcode Printer (B-EP902-LL-QM-R)",
    "122": "10021165282 - Barcode Printer (B-EP904-LL-QM-R)",
    "123": "10021165233 - Barcode Printer (B-SA704-IO-QM-R)",
    "124": "10021165234 - Barcode Printer (B-4205-QM-R)",
    "125": "10021165236 - Barcode Printer (B-8204-QM-R)",
    "126": "10021165239 - Barcode Printer (B-9700-PCM-QM-R)",
    "127": "18221165329 - Barcode Printer (B-EX904-PK-QM-R)",
    "128": "18221165331 - Barcode Printer (B-EX700-I0-QM-R)",
    "129": "18221165332 - Barcode Printer (B-EX700-CEN-QM-R)",
    "130": "18221165333 - Barcode Printer (B-EX700-RS-QM-R)",
    "131": "18221165334 - Barcode Printer (B-EX700-WLAN-QM-R)",
    "132": "18221165342 - Barcode Printer (B-EX206-QM-R)",
    "133": "18221165343 - Barcode Printer (B-EX906-H-QM-R)",
    "134": "18221165364 - Barcode Printer (B-FV204T-F-QM-R)",
    "135": "18221165365 - Barcode Printer (B-FV204D-F-QM-R)",
    "136": "18221165366 - Barcode Printer (B-FV204T-P-QM-R)",
    "137": "18221165367 - Barcode Printer (B-FV204D-P-QM-R)",
    "138": "18221165368 - Barcode Printer (B-FV204T-H-QM-R)",
    "139": "18221165369 - Barcode Printer (B-FV204D-H-QM-R)",
    "140": "18221165374 - Barcode Printer (B-FV700-WLAN-QM-R)",
    "141": "18221165375 - Barcode Printer (B-FV700-BLTH-QM-R)",
    "142": "18221165388 - Barcode Printer (B-EX906-FF-QM-R)",
    "143": "18221165389 - Barcode Printer (B-EX700-WLAN2-QM-R)",
    "144": "18221165390 - Barcode Printer (B-EX706-RFID-U4-US/EU/AU)",
    "145": "18221165393 - Barcode Printer (B-FP803-BT-QM-R)",
    "146": "18221165395 - Barcode Printer (B-FP800-WCHGU-QM-R)",
    "147": "18221165396 - Barcode Printer (B-FP800-DCJA-QM-R)",
    "148": "18221165398 - Barcode Printer (B-FP803-BTH-QM-R)",
    "149": "18221168664 - Barcode Printer (B-SA4TM-GS12-QM-R)",
    "150": "18221168665 - Barcode Printer (B-SA4TM-TS12-QM-R)",
    "151": "18221168675 - Barcode Printer (B-SA4TP-GS12-QM-R)",
    "152": "18221168676 - Barcode Printer (B-SA4TP-TS12-QM-R)",
    "153": "18221168679 - Barcode Printer (B-SX5T-TS22-QM-R)",
    "154": "18221168683 - Barcode Printer (B-852-TS22-QP-R)",
    "155": "18221168684 - Barcode Printer (B-SX6T-TS12-QM-R)",
    "156": "18221168685 - Barcode Printer (B-SX8T-TS12-QM-R)",
    "157": "18221168699 - Barcode Printer (B-452-TS22-QP-R)",
    "158": "18221168702 - Barcode Printer (B-EP2DL-GH20-QM-R)",
    "159": "18221168704 - Barcode Printer (B-EP2DL-GH40-QM-R)",
    "160": "18221168705 - Barcode Printer (B-EP4DL-GH20-QM-R)",
    "161": "18221168707 - Barcode Printer (B-EP4DL-GH40-QM-R)",
    "162": "18221168711 - Barcode Printer (B-EV4D-GS14-QM-R)",
    "163": "18221168712 - Barcode Printer (B-EV4D-TS14-QM-R)",
    "164": "18221168713 - Barcode Printer (B-EV4T-GS14-QM-R)",
    "165": "18221168714 - Barcode Printer (B-EV4T-TS14-QM-R)",
    "166": "18221168732 - Barcode Printer (B-EX4T1-GS12-QM-R)",
    "167": "18221168733 - Barcode Printer (B-EX4T1-TS12-QM-R)",
    "168": "18221168737 - Barcode Printer (DB-EA4D-GS10-QM-R)",
    "169": "18221168742 - Barcode Printer (B-EX4T2-GS12-QM-R)",
    "170": "18221168743 - Barcode Printer (B-EX4T2-TS12-QM-R)",
    "171": "18221168746 - Barcode Printer (B-EX4T2-HS12-QM-R)",
    "172": "18221168793 - Barcode Printer (B-FV4T-GS12-QM-R (Type 1))",
    "173": "18221168798 - Barcode Printer (B-FV4T-TS12-QM-R (Type 1))",
    "174": "18221168803 - Barcode Printer (B-FV4D-GS12-QM-R (Type1))",
    "175": "18221168808 - Barcode Printer (B-FV4D-TS12-QM-R (Type1))",
    "176": "18221168843 - Barcode Printer (B-EX6T1-TS12-QM-R)",
    "177": "18221168847 - Barcode Printer (B-EX6T1-GS12-QM-R)",
    "178": "18221168851 - Barcode Printer (B-EX6T3-TS12-QM-R)",
    "179": "18221168853 - Barcode Printer (B-EX6T3-GS12-QM-R)",
    "180": "18221168856 - Barcode Printer (B-FB3D-GH30-QM-R)",
    "181": "18221168858 - Barcode Printer (B-FP3D-GH40-QM-R)",
    "182": "18221168864 - Barcode Printer (B-FP3D-GS30-QM-R)",
    "183": "18221168866 - Barcode Printer (B-FP3D-GS40-QM-R)",
    "184": "18221168872 - Barcode Printer (B-EP2DL-GH32-QM-R)",
    "185": "18221168873 - Barcode Printer (B-EP4DL-GH32-QM-R)",
    "186": "18221168912 - Barcode Printer (B-EX4T3-HS12-QM-R)",
    "187": "MHT00014 - Cash Drawer (ECH 410 RJ-11)",
    "188": "10021165231 - CUTTER MODULE SA4TM (B-SA204-QM-R)",
    "189": "47500 - FARGO (DTC 1000 Upgrade)",
    "190": "51976 - Fargo Card Printer (C50 card printer)",
    "191": "89001 - Fargo Card Printer (HDP5000 Flipper Module\t\t\t)",
    "192": "89336 - Fargo Card Printer (HDP5000 Single Side Printer)",
    "193": "MHT00298 - GP Scanner (Koohii EC100 Barcode Scanner)",
    "194": "MHT00232 - HAND HELD (EC100)",
    "195": "MHT00319 - HAND HELD 2D SCANNER (Hh660  2D scanner)",
    "196": "MHT00378 - postek label printer (EM210 )",
    "197": "MHT00236 - RF TAGS (410 D LABEL)",
    "198": "MHT00335 - RFID reader (KD106U)",
    "199": "mht00330 - Scanner (HH400)",
    "200": "MHT00281 - Scanner (VISITING CARD SCANNER)",
    "201": "140416057 - Scanner ()",
    "202": "MHT00015 - Scanner ()",
    "203": "MHT00016 - Scanner ()",
    "204": "MHT00017 - Scanner ()",
    "205": "MHT00018 - Scanner ()",
    "206": "MHT00019 - Scanner ()",
    "207": "MHT00020 - Scanner ()",
    "208": "MHT00021 - Scanner ()",
    "209": "MHT00055 - Scanner ()",
    "210": "MHT00001 - Scanner ()",
    "211": "MHT00023 - Scanner ()",
    "212": "MHT00024 - Scanner ()",
    "213": "MHT00025 - Scanner ()",
    "214": "MHT00026 - Scanner ()",
    "215": "MHT00027 - Scanner ()",
    "216": "MHT00028 - Scanner ()",
    "217": "MHT00029 - Scanner ()",
    "218": "MHT00030 - Scanner ()",
    "219": "MHT00031 - Scanner ()",
    "220": "MHT00032 - Scanner ()",
    "221": "MHT00033 - Scanner ()",
    "222": "MHT00034 - Scanner ()",
    "223": "MHT00035 - Scanner ()",
    "224": "MHT00036 - Scanner ()",
    "225": "MHT00037 - Scanner ()",
    "226": "MHT00038 - Scanner ()",
    "227": "MHT00039 - Scanner ()",
    "228": "MHT00040 - Scanner ()",
    "229": "MHT00041 - Scanner ()",
    "230": "MHT00042 - Scanner ()",
    "231": "MHT00043 - Scanner ()",
    "232": "MHT00044 - Scanner ()",
    "233": "MHT00045 - Scanner ()",
    "234": "MHT00046 - Scanner ()",
    "235": "MHT00047 - Scanner ()",
    "236": "MHT00048 - Scanner ()",
    "237": "MHT00049 - Scanner ()",
    "238": "MHT00050 - Scanner ()",
    "239": "MHT00051 - Scanner ()",
    "240": "MHT00052 - Scanner ()",
    "241": "MHT00053 - Scanner ()",
    "242": "MHT00003 - Scanner ()",
    "243": "MHT00004 - Scanner ()",
    "244": "MHT00005 - Scanner ()",
    "245": "MHT00006 - Scanner ()",
    "246": "MHT00007 - Scanner ()",
    "247": "MHT00008 - Scanner ()",
    "248": "MHT00009 - Scanner ()",
    "249": "MHT00010 - Scanner ()",
    "250": "MHT00011 - Scanner ()",
    "251": "MHT00012 - Scanner ()",
    "252": "MHT00013 - Scanner ()",
    "253": "160622V1114ABNQ - Thermal Printer (GP-U80300I)",
    "254": "18221165370 - Toshiba Spares (B-FV904-PH-QM-R)",
    "255": "506339-001 - Id Card Printer (SD360)",
    "256": "51722 - Id Card Printer (FARGO DTC 1250E Dual Side)",
    "257": "MHT00263 - Pre printed Cards ()",
    "258": "MHT00224 - Pre printed Cards (HMP Dual side PP card)",
    "259": "MHT00292 - Scanner (MK 7120)",
    "260": "MHT00328 - AVERY SILVER POLYSTER (75*50MM)",
    "261": "MHT00347 - barcode (38*20 1ac 3\" core 2000(per roll))",
    "262": "MHT00348 - Barcode Label (30mm*22mm )",
    "263": "MHT00323 - BARCODE RIBBON (55*100)",
    "264": "MHT00234 - Barcode Ribbon (ATW12A-065X074 mtr 0.5 core)",
    "265": "MHT00253 - Barcode Ribbon (040x300 AS1, 1AC)",
    "266": "MHT00254 - Barcode Ribbon (110x300 AG2, 1AC)",
    "267": "MHT00256 - Barcode Ribbon (040mmx300m AXR7+)",
    "268": "MHT00257 - Barcode Ribbon (110mmx300m AXR7+)",
    "269": "MHT00282 - Barcode Ribbon (110mmx300m APR600)",
    "270": "BX730070AG2005 - Barcode Ribbon (70x300 AG2)",
    "271": "BX730090AS1005 - Barcode Ribbon (90x300 AS1)",
    "272": "BX730110AG2005 - Barcode Ribbon (110x300 AG2)",
    "273": "BX730112AG2005 - Barcode Ribbon (112x300 AG2 )",
    "274": "BX730130AG2005 - Barcode Ribbon (130x300 AG2)",
    "275": "B4527060AG3010 - Barcode Ribbon (60x270 AG3)",
    "276": "B4527090AG3011 - Barcode Ribbon (90x270 AG3)",
    "277": "B4530060AW6F010 - Barcode Ribbon (60x300 AW6F)",
    "278": "B4530110AW6F010 - Barcode Ribbon (110x300 AW6F)",
    "279": "BEV100110AW6F025 - Barcode Ribbon (110x100 AW3)",
    "280": "BEV10055AS1025 - Barcode Ribbon (55x100 AS1)",
    "281": "BEV10055AW6F025 - Barcode Ribbon (55x100 AW6F)",
    "282": "BEX45110AW6F - Barcode Ribbon (110x450 AW6F)",
    "283": "MHT00076 - Barcode Ribbon (110x100 AS1)",
    "284": "MHT00351 - chrome label (50*17 1\" core)",
    "285": "534700-004-R002 - Datacard color Ribbon (YMCKT Full color)",
    "286": "534000-003 - Datacard color Ribbon (YMCKT Full color)",
    "287": "534700-106-R002 - Datacard Half Panel 435 Images (SD360)",
    "288": "534700-002-R002 - Datacard Half Panel 650 Images (SD360)",
    "289": "81754 - FARGO (PVC ultra card)",
    "290": "84051 - Fargo Ribbon (YMCK HDP5000 color ribbon)",
    "291": "84052 - Fargo Ribbon (YMCKK - 500 Color images)",
    "292": "84053 - Fargo Ribbon (HDP Film - 1500 images)",
    "293": "44261 - Fargo Ribbon (ECO Refillable Catridge only)",
    "294": "45029 - Fargo Ribbon ()",
    "295": "45065 - Fargo Ribbon ()",
    "296": "45102 - Fargo Ribbon (Black ribbon)",
    "297": "45117 - Fargo Ribbon (Black Monochrome Ribbon)",
    "298": "45200 - Fargo Ribbon (YMCK 500)",
    "299": "45500 - Fargo Ribbon (EZ Full color YMCKO)",
    "300": "45510 - Fargo Ribbon (YMCKOK Full Color)",
    "301": "45515 - Fargo Ribbon (YMCKO FULL PANEL)",
    "302": "45516 - Fargo Ribbon (YMCKOK - 200 Images)",
    "303": "45601 - Fargo Ribbon ()",
    "304": "MHT00294 - Mifare - 1K Plain (MF1K)",
    "305": "MHT00244 - Plain Card (PVC Plain Card)",
    "306": "MHT00075 - Plain Card (Plain Card with Tag)",
    "307": "MHT00071 - Plain Card (Adhar Card)",
    "308": "MHT00072 - Plain Card (Access Card)",
    "309": "MHT00073 - Plain Chrome Label (075*50 1AC)",
    "310": "MHT00074 - Plain Chrome Label (050*025 1AC)",
    "311": "MHT00060 - Plain Chrome Label (025x020, 4 AC)",
    "312": "MHT00061 - Plain Chrome Label (079x060)",
    "313": "MHT00064 - Plain Chrome Label (070x080)",
    "314": "MHT00065 - Plain Chrome Label (035*065 1AC)",
    "315": "MHT00078 - Plain Chrome Label (100*050 1AC)",
    "316": "MHT00079 - Plain Chrome Label (080*035 1AC)",
    "317": "MHT00080 - Plain Chrome Label (100*150 1AC)",
    "318": "MHT00081 - Plain Chrome Label (220x290)",
    "319": "MHT00082 - Plain Chrome Label (050*050 1AC)",
    "320": "MHT00083 - Plain Chrome Label (038*020 1AC)",
    "321": "MHT00084 - Plain Chrome Label (035*022 3AC)",
    "322": "MHT00057 - Plain Chrome Label (100*075)",
    "323": "MHT00226 - Plain Chrome Label (070*160 1AC)",
    "324": "MHT00087 - Plain Chrome Label (050*025 1AC)",
    "325": "MHT00096 - Plain Chrome Label (040*012 1AC)",
    "326": "MHT00097 - Plain Chrome Label (090*060 1AC)",
    "327": "MHT00098 - Plain Chrome Label (025*025 4AC)",
    "328": "MHT00068 - Plain Chrome Label (025x022 1 AC)",
    "329": "MHT00069 - Plain Chrome Label (040*025 1AC)",
    "330": "MHT00070 - Plain Chrome Label (206*280 1AC)",
    "331": "MHT00100 - Plain Chrome Label (035*022 3AC)",
    "332": "MHT00247 - Plain Chrome Label (075x075  1AC)",
    "333": "MHT00248 - Plain Chrome Label (050x016  1AC)",
    "334": "MHT00240 - Plain Chrome Label (050*035 1AC)",
    "335": "MHT00241 - Plain Chrome Label (060x040 1AC)",
    "336": "MHT00288 - Plain Chrome Label (100x150mm 1AC)",
    "337": "MHT00277 - Plain Chrome Label (050x025 2AC)",
    "338": "MHT00258 - Plain Chrome Label (100*300)",
    "339": "MHT00255 - Plain Chrome Label (070x160mm  1 AC)",
    "340": "MHT00251 - Plain Chrome Label (060x030mm  1 AC)",
    "341": "MHT00252 - Plain Chrome Label (080x070mm  1 AC)",
    "342": "MHT00260 - Plain Chrome Label (050x025 1AC,1.5\"Core )",
    "343": "MHT00261 - Plain Chrome Label (050*025 1AC)",
    "344": "MHT00262 - Plain Chrome Label (080x070mm 1AC)",
    "345": "MHT00266 - Plain Chrome Label (038*028 1AC)",
    "346": "MHT00267 - Plain Chrome Label (050x025 1AC)",
    "347": "MHT00296 - Plain Chrome Label (060x030mm  1\" core )",
    "348": "MHT00305 - Plain Chrome Label (075x075  1AC )",
    "349": "MHT00306 - Plain Chrome Label (100*100 1AC)",
    "350": "MHT00307 - Plain Chrome Label (100*35 1AC)",
    "351": "MHT00309 - Plain Chrome Label (070x160mm  1 AC)",
    "352": "MHT00349 - Plain Chrome Label (50*60)",
    "353": "MHT00361 - Plain Chrome Label (90*60  veg logo)",
    "354": "MHT00362 - Plain Chrome Label (80*70  1ac  tte)",
    "355": "MHT00363 - Plain Chrome Label (80*70  1ac  tte)",
    "356": "MHT00364 - Plain Chrome Label (60*35 1\"core )",
    "357": "MHT00318 - Plain Chrome Label (100*150 1AC)",
    "358": "MHT00336 - Plain Chrome Label (50*25)",
    "359": "MHT00331 - Plain Chrome Label (038*028 1AC)",
    "360": "MHT00332 - Plain Chrome Label (100*50 1AC- 3\"-2000/roll)",
    "361": "MHT00333 - Plain Chrome Label (34*20)",
    "362": "MHT00376 - Plain Chrome Label (30*15( 3 UPS ))",
    "363": "MHT00265 - Plain Ribbon (055*100)",
    "364": "MHT00099 - Plain Thermal Paper ()",
    "365": "MHT00320 - Plain Thermal Paper (79*50M)",
    "366": "MHT00321 - Plain Thermal Paper (79*60M)",
    "367": "MHT00280 - Polaroid Ribbon (P3000+ YMCKT)",
    "368": "MHT00379 - POLISTER LABEL (100*50)",
    "369": "MHT00279 - Polyster  (040x020 1\"core)",
    "370": "MHT00290 - Polyster (016*050 mm 1 AC)",
    "371": "MHT00285 - Polyster  (050x008 1\"core)",
    "372": "MHT00287 - Polyster  (040mmx020mm 1\"core)",
    "373": "MHT00235 - Polyster  (075x050 1AC)",
    "374": "MHT00237 - Polyster  (008x050mm 1AC)",
    "375": "MHT00238 - Polyster  (050x025 1AC Poly)",
    "376": "MHT00311 - Polyster  (065x030mm  1\" core )",
    "377": "MHT00312 - Polyster  (020x025mm  1\" core )",
    "378": "MHT00316 - Polyster  (065x030mm  1\" core )",
    "379": "MHT00317 - Polyster  (025x020mm  1\" core )",
    "380": "MHT00304 - Polyster  (038*020 2AC)",
    "381": "MHT00345 - POLYSTER (30X30MM with 10mm CUT-1\"core-1000 label/roll)",
    "382": "MHT00346 - Polyster  (30x20mm polyster-2AC - 1 \"- 2500/Roll)",
    "383": "MHT00243 - Pre Printed Synthetic (031x022mm  2 Across)",
    "384": "MHT00231 - Pre Printed TAGS (90X60MM-1\"Core -500/roll)",
    "385": "MHT00284 - Premium Wax Resin (092mmx300m B120E)",
    "386": "MHT00272 - Premium Wax Resin (110x100m  0.5\"Core)",
    "387": "MHT00344 - Premium Wax Resin (170*300Mtr-1\" core, Pre Wax Res-20N)",
    "388": "MHT00314 - Premium Wax Resin (110x300m  1\"Core)",
    "389": "MHT00369 - Premium Wax Resin (ATM 20N 105*74)",
    "390": "MHT00002 - Premium Wax Resin (060x300m \ufffd1\"core)",
    "391": "MHT00367 - PREMIUM WAX RIBBON (110*300)",
    "392": "MHT00274 - Resin Ribbon (110x270m 1\"core)",
    "393": "MHT00215 - Resin Ribbon ()",
    "394": "MHT00268 - Resin Ribbon - NK22 (110x300 0.5 core)",
    "395": "MHT00313 - Resin Ribbon - NK22 (110x100m 0.5 core)",
    "396": "MHT00293 - Resin Ribbon - NK22 (110x270 1\"core)",
    "397": "MHT00229 - RESIN WASH CARE (AT50-040x300 Mtr 1\" Core)",
    "398": "MHT00278 - RFID Card (RFID Card)",
    "399": "MHT00056 - RFID Card (RFID Card)",
    "400": "MHT00356 - SATIN RIBBON ROLL (PS062A1 15MM)",
    "401": "MHT00357 - SATIN RIBBON ROLL (PS062A1 20MM)",
    "402": "MHT00358 - SATIN RIBBON ROLL (NT684A110MM)",
    "403": "MHT00359 - SATIN RIBBON ROLL (NT688A1 15MM)",
    "404": "MHT00360 - SATIN RIBBON ROLL (NT688A1 20MM)",
    "405": "MHT00355 - SATIN ROLL (PS061A1 10MM)",
    "406": "mht00342 - sattin wash care ribbon (40mm*300)",
    "407": "MHT00246 - Sticky Card (Sticky Card)",
    "408": "MHT00249 - Synthetic Label (080x070mm  1 AC)",
    "409": "MHT00250 - Synthetic Label (060x030mm  1 AC)",
    "410": "MHT00239 - Synthetic Label (025x022-1AC)",
    "411": "MHT00242 - Synthetic Label (031x022mm  2 Across)",
    "412": "MHT00343 - Synthetic Label (45X30-10mm CUT-1AC-1\"CORE-1000/ROLL)",
    "413": "MHT00295 - Synthetic Label (090*050 1\"core)",
    "414": "MHT00370 - Synthetic Label (8*50)",
    "415": "MHT00371 - Synthetic Label (16*50)",
    "416": "MHT00372 - Synthetic Label (25*50)",
    "417": "MHT00085 - Synthetic Label (070*080 1AC)",
    "418": "MHT00308 - Thermal Paper (182mm Width x 400 meter)",
    "419": "BSA204QMR - Toshiba Spares (B-SA4TM cutter Module)",
    "420": "MHT00315 - TTR Ribbon (110*270)",
    "421": "MHT00225 - TTR Ribbon (110*270)",
    "422": "MHT00230 - Wax Ribbon (14A 155x300Mtr)",
    "423": "MHT00273 - Wax Ribbon (110x300m 1\"core ATW12A)",
    "424": "MHT00283 - Wax Ribbon (060mmx75m 0.5\" Core)",
    "425": "MHT00269 - Wax Ribbon (110x270  1\"core)",
    "426": "MHT00270 - Wax Ribbon (060x300m  1\"core)",
    "427": "MHT00271 - Wax Ribbon (065x74m 0.5\" Core)",
    "428": "MHT00259 - Wax Ribbon (110*300)",
    "429": "mht00341 - Wax Ribbon (60*300m 1\" core)",
    "430": "MHT00066 - Wax Ribbon ()",
    "431": "MHT00067 - Wax Ribbon ()",
    "432": "MHT00058 - Wax Ribbon (060x270m)",
    "433": "MHT00059 - Wax Ribbon (110x074)",
    "434": "MHT00275 - Woven Satin (035mm )",
    "435": "534100-005 - YMCKT 500 FULL PANEL (SD360 Full Panel)",
    "436": "534700-001-R002 - YMCKT 500 FULL PANEL (SD360 Full Panel)",
    "437": "534700-005-R002 - YMCKT-KT 350 Images (SD360 Full Panel)",
    "438": "MHT00322 - ZEBRA RIBBON (P1029933-003)",
    "439": "MHT00366 - empty cartridge casette ()",
    "440": "MHT00365 - instlation (Testing  training)",
    "441": "SGP256200 - UPS (UPS Server)",
    "442": "MHT00310 - Thermal printer (GP 1415)",
    "443": "MHT00297 - Thermal printer (GP 1125T SUEP)",
    "444": "MHT00233 - Thermal printer (GP U80300I SUE)",
    "445": "MHT00327 - ID Soft-Card Printing Database interfacing (Single User)",
    "446": "MHT00375 - ThoughtGST (ThoughtBit)",
    "447": "7M07218000 - ASYB-PCB6-SA-SVP FRU(SA4T) (B-SA4TM)",
    "448": "7FM01970100 - B-852 FDD GAP SENSOR TR ROHS (B-852-TS22-QP-R)",
    "449": "OTSBC0112401F - Toshiba Spares (B-EX4T Platen Roller)",
    "450": "OTSBC0145201F - BARCODE PRINT HEAD (B EX4T2 HS 600DPI)",
    "451": "MHT00350 - codless scanner (PDT 3E  BARCODE SCANNER)",
    "452": "7FM00920000 - DAMPER HOLDER (BSA4-TM)",
    "453": "FO-01831000 - DAMPER OTU10-8-064 (BSA4-TM)",
    "454": "FO-01830000 - DAMPER OTU8-4-063 (BSA4-TM)",
    "455": "7FM00966100 - DAMPER ROLLER (B-SA4 TM)",
    "456": "7FM01052000 - LCD PC BOARD (BSA-4TM)",
    "457": "F7FM04858000 - MAIN PC BOARD ASSY (EX4T1 /T2)",
    "458": "OTSBC0127901F - MEDIA SENSOR ASSY (WITH HARNESS) (B-EX4T1/T2)",
    "459": "FMCB0104101 - MEDIA SENSOR HARNESS (B-852-TS22-QP-R)",
    "460": "FMBCOO90103 - OPERATION PANEL ASS\"Y (B-852-TS22-QP-R)",
    "461": "7FM00716100 - PANEL PC BOARD (BSA-4TM)",
    "462": "FMBD0042302 - PAPER GUIDE ASS\"Y (B-852-TS22-QP-R)",
    "463": "7FM03681000 - PAPER GUIDE ASSY (B-EX6T)",
    "464": "7FM01589000 - PLATEN ASSY (B-SX6T/5T)",
    "465": "07fm00163000f - platen sx fru (sx5t)",
    "466": "7FM06974100 - PLATEN-ROLLER-EX6T-ASSY FRU (B-EX6T)",
    "467": "8VD00999100 - POER SUPPLY PC BOARD ASS\"Y (BSA-4TM)",
    "468": "7FM00594000 - POWER SUPPLY UNIT (B SX5T)",
    "469": "0TSBC0113901F - POWER SUPPLY UNIT (B-EX4T1 PSU)",
    "470": "0TSBC0145201F - Printer Head (B EX4T2 HS600 Dpi Print Head)",
    "471": "0FMBC0089706F - Printer Head (B 852)",
    "472": "7FM06508000 - PRINTER HEAD (FV4T-300DPI)"
```

how to show this data in swift

Comment: Line 390 `...\ufffd1\"` looks queer.

Comment: in postman works fine and swift not getting and I don't how to deal this type of data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one,I solved this .Actually this is not my error there was error in son data line 190